# Visual Studio 2015 localhost images suddenly stopped loading - 500 error (ASP 5 MVC 6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, localhost

I have a ASP.NET 5, MVC 6 project in Visual Studio 2015 and all of a sudden, when I ran the project on localhost, my images gave 500 errors. That being said, not all of them - most of them. Every few times I run the project different ones appear correctly (1 or 2 appear correctly maximum at any given time). I image paths are correct and when i copy and past the url from the img tags, they appear correctly. Also, the img tags are correct because they will rotate showing up. The css is loading correctly.

This is freaking me out and totally sucks because I wanted to keep working on developing the actual app. I have no idea why it's happening

any and all help appreciated!

Comment: Then use you browser tools  (Network tab) to inspect the response - it will give you the details of the error.

Comment: how do i check the error details? it just says 500 internal server error. i also noticed it says type "text/plain" maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: Use the Network tab, the calls with errors will be highlighted, then click on it and view the error details in the Response tab

Comment: "This request has no response data available"